# Azure DevOps how to get file name in output (drop) folder after publishing build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure DevOps to build a python wheel. I want to make it as generic as possible so that everyone in the team can use the same pipeline to build their own python wheels and deploying them in some databricks workspace. For that I need to know what the name of the file(s) in build pipeline output is to use it in my release pipeline.

Currently in this case the file is a python wheel saved in build pipeline output. I am using the following code in my pipeline yaml to publish it both at build pipeline output and an Azure artifact feed.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
      pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: dfordbx

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/
    vstsFeedPublish: 'MyProject/py_artifacts_1732'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: $(packageBuildName)
```

After build pipeline run ends, there is one wheel file in dist folder. I need to get the name of this wheel. For my own code, I of course know the name. But when others run the pipeline for their code, this is not clear to me. I require to get this name in my release pipeline.

In other words, I am looking for a way in my yaml file to get "py_sample_package-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl" name in the following structure:

By choosing published artifact:

[image]

Getting to the file:

[image]

The highlighted part is what I need to get in pipeline. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Classic Release Pipelines

In a Classic Release pipeline, you reference a build artifact and use it as a trigger. Artifacts are downloaded to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)`.

To identify the `.whl` file in the artifact, add a powershell script into your release pipeline that identifies the file and creates a new variable using the  [`##vso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) logging syntax...

For example:

```
# find the first .whl file in the artifact folder
$whlFile = Get-ChildItem `
              -Filter *.whl `
              -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\dfordbx" |
           ForEach-Object { $_.fullname } |
           Select-Object -First 1
        
# create a variable with the full path to the file
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=whlFile]$whlFile"
```

Now you can use the variable like any other defined pipeline variable `$(whlFile)`

## Multi-Stage YAML Pipelines

If you're using a multi-stage YAML pipeline and need to use the artifact between stages, you can't assume that the file will be present on the machine because each job is potentially running on a different machine. You will need to download the artifact at the start of  the job.

```yaml
variables:
- artifactName: dfordbx

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: buildJob
    steps: 
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: $(artifactName)
        artifactType: 'pipeline'
    
    # or use the 'publish' alias
    - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: '$(artifactName)'
 

- stage: deploy
  dependsOn: build
  condition: success('build')
  jobs:
  - job: deployJob
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        source: 'current'
        artifact: $(artifactName)
        path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(artifactName)'
    
    # or use the 'download' alias
    - download: current
      artifact: $(artifactName)

    - pwsh: |
        $whlFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(artifactName)" -Filter *.whl |
                   ForEach-Object { $_.fullName } |
                   Select-Object -First 1
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=whlFile]$whlFile"
```

Comment: Thanks @bryangbcook I tried your code, but the path you mentioned seemed to be empty. I changed it to "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/dist" and the wheel is there. However,   when I try to get its value by - pwsh: | Write-Host "Wheel name is $env:whlFile" it is again empty. I used - bash: | echo "$(whlFile)" and it returns a value but it is not the wheel alone. It returned the whole path together with wheel name: /home/vsts/work/1/a/dist/py_sample_package-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl. Can you plz tell me how to only get the wheel out of it?

Comment: I had to try more than 20 combinations to figure out where the wheel was. The "dist" in -Path "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/dist" is due to python creating a wheel. But generally speaking how do you know where the artifact can be found in build or release pipeline? To figure this out I tried "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)", "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)", "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" and even combinations like "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.DefinitionName)/dfordbx", "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dfordbx" and at the end found it in "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/dist"

Comment: One other thing, my pipeline has three stages. I am deploying the built wheel to databricks immediately after build pipeline is finished. Can variables defining in one stage, be used in a different stage if you define dependencies?

Comment: You didn't clarify what your "release pipeline" was. I assumed you were using a Classic Release pipeline where you are referencing the build artifact as the trigger for the pipeline.  You can get variables to work across stages, but each job potentially runs on a different machine so the file path isn't guaranteed. I can update my answer to show how you can use variables across stages and how you can download artifacts if needed.

Comment: @bryanbcook Will this approach work between Pipelines i.e. PipelineA publishes the build artifacts and calls PipelineB through trigger, PipelineB then downloads and consumes the built files?